# What timezone is used in the API?

Tags: support, api, javascript

When a timestamp is used, for example the `fromdate` parameter in [/questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=questions), what timezone are dates in?  Is the number supposed to be in milliseconds or in seconds?

To get the current time to pass as a parameter in JavaScript should  I use:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

or:

```
Math.round(((new Date()).getTime()-Date.UTC(1970,0,1))/1000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date is Unix Epoch time, which is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.  The "time zone" is UTC, which is nearly equivalent to GMT.  You can convert from UTC to local time in javascript using the method outlined [here](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6016329.html).

Here are the functions I use to convert back and forth (code is C#):

```
public static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}

public static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
    return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: +1 although UTC is not a Time Zone but a time standard and Time Zones are expressed as negative or positive offsets from UTC.

Comment: @system: true dat.  Updated.